# C# How to get properties names as strings of generic class using nameof

Tags: c#, properties, nameof

C# How to get properties names of generic class using nameof without specifing a type.
I have class as follow:

```
public class Example<T> where T : class
{
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now; 
}
```

And I want to get "CreateAt" as string using following:

```
nameof(Example<>.CreatedAt)
```

but it doesn't work, I need to specify the type:

```
nameof(Example<int>.CreatedAt)
```

Although, for checking the type I can use construction:

```
typeof(BaseEntity<>)
```

Why it doesn't work with nameof? Why do I need to define the type?

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/702, from 2017

Comment: you need to specify *a* type; it doesn't need to be *the* type; any type (that satisfies the generic constraints, if any) will work fine (and identically)

Comment: Ok @canton7 thanks, so it seems that we haven't had developed such a thing yet..

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, If I understand correctly, will it work as far as we don't change generic constraints?

Comment: @ElConrado yes, that'll be fine - and it only impacts compile, since `nameof` is erased during compile and literally doesn't exist at runtime - so if the generic constraints do change (unlikely), that will never cause a surprise break at runtime; worst cast is that it fails next time you build, and you need to change to a different dummy type - i.e. instead of `nameof(Example<int>.CreatedAt)` you might use `nameof(Example<string>.CreatedAt)` (because, for example, someone added a `where T : class` constraint)